# ROSCORE - not running due to python package missing

Tags: ros, catkin, installation, roscore, ros-noetic

I have installed the ROS noetic and when I tried to run the roscore command, I get an error. Ive already tired re-installing the ROS environment, but it didnt help to solve the issue. Can anyone guide me on how to solve this issue?

```bash
$ roscore
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/bin/roscore", line 37, in <module>
    from roslaunch.nodeprocess import DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_SIGINT, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_SIGTERM
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .launch import ROSLaunchRunner
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/roslaunch/launch.py", line 58, in <module>
    from roslaunch.rlutil import update_terminal_name
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/roslaunch/rlutil.py", line 47, in <module>
    import rosclean
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosclean/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from distutils.spawn import find_executable
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.spawn'
```

Comment: It sounds like there's an issue with your distutils installation What does `python3 -c 'import distutils; help(distutils)'` say the version and file is?